# import db from a large(200 GB) mysqldump file

Tags: mysql

I import a db from a large mysqldump file, the file is about 200GB, after import, the db shows only partial tables, some tables were not imported.  The process produced no error. here are the commands:

```
nohup mysql -uroot -ppass db_name <dumpfile.sql &
```

Comment: if you backgrounded it without directing stdout/stderr to a file, how do you know that no errors or warnings were actually produced?

Comment: it redirected output to nohup.out by default

Comment: Any reason you did that with nohup and &? Can you retry that in screen? Can you check that the partial tables are complete in that dumpfile.sql?

Comment: because it's a remote server and I use ssh terminal to do it, there are tables in that dumpfile that doesn't exist in the final db.

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a single dump for each table then no need to do the whole import on failure.

Suppose your db is named MyTestDB

```
$ mysql -u<dbuser> -p<dbpass> -h<dbhost> MyTestDB -e "SHOW TABLES" > ./tablelist.txt
```

That creates a table list file in the current directory
Now dump the tables to a folder called dbdump

```
$ for table in `cat ./tablelist.txt`; do echo $table; mysqldump -u<dbuser> -p<dbpass> -h<dbhost> MyTestDB $table > ./dbdump/$table.sql
```

Similarly to import it into the db

```
$ for table in `cat ./tablelist.txt`; do echo $table; mysql -u<dbuser> -p<dbpass> -h<dbhost> MyTestDB  < ./dbdump/$table.sql
```